# ASP.NET webforms build event

Tags: .net, reactjs, webforms, msbuild

So basically I am attempting to have a build step that will change directory into my `./Clientapp` folder and run an npm script that bundles the react app.

I tried something like this [Build step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019) with a batch file in the root directory. But no luck with the batch file. Was getting `CD is unrecognized`. But I want this build step to work in CI/CD as well, so that is why I went with a .bat file but wondering if there is a way in web.config instead to do this.

I think the build step should also be `Before Build (Pre)` because the bundles need to be included in wwwroot I am guessing.

Anyone know a good way to do this?

Project is using .NET 4.6.2 and Web Forms and VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new target that runs before the build.

Inside that target just use the Exec task to execute your npm command.
You can set the WorkingDirectory for this command, so no need to do a 'CD'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2019